# How to fix "ActionView::Template::Error" in Heroku/Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Some helpful message for your future self"
```

in my terminal. I have also pushed my rails application onto Heroku, and I've ran:

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

My app shows the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error though.
This is what shows up in my logs:

```
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687554+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-28T00:08:13.687495 #4] FATAL -- : [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47] ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]):
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687702+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-28T00:08:13.687649 #4] FATAL -- : [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     26:     <div class="center-one">
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687705+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     27:       <table>
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687706+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     28:         <tr>
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687708+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     29:           <th class="table-header"><%= link_to 'community', category_path(@community) %></th>
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687710+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     30:         </tr>
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687711+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     31:         <tr>
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687713+00:00 app[web.1]: [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]     32:           <td>
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687741+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-28T00:08:13.687697 #4] FATAL -- : [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47]   
2019-07-28T00:08:13.687806+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-07-28T00:08:13.687747 #4] FATAL -- : [b4dfe4a3-136d-499a-83f1-be0d4e82fb47] app/views/categories/index.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_categories_index_html_erb___3528218001569079456_46996040052660'
2019-07-28T00:08:14.760735+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=damare.herokuapp.com request_id=78e904dc-8e9b-4849-ba3e-a137dd23ba60 fwd="71.140.151.125" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
```

This is my categories_controller.rb file:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @community = @categories[0]
    @housing = @categories[1]
    @jobs = @categories[2]
    @personals = @categories[3]
    @services = @categories[4]
    @for_sale = @categories[5]
  end
  def show
    @listings = Listing.where(category_id: params[:id])
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :categories do
    resources :subcategories
  end
  resources :listings do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
  root 'categories#index'
  match '/help', to: 'pages#help', via: :get
  match '/scams', to: 'pages#scams', via: :get
  match '/safety', to: 'pages#safety', via: :get
  match '/terms', to: 'pages#terms', via: :get
  match '/privacy', to: 'pages#privacy', via: :get
  match '/about', to: 'pages#about', via: :get
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact', via: :get
  match '/mylistings', to: 'listings#mylistings', via: :get
  match '/subcategoires/find_by_category', to: 'subcategories#find_by_category', via: :post
end
```

Url of the page:
https://damare.herokuapp.com/

The categories are created in my seeds.rb file:

```
community_category = Category.where(name: 'community').first_or_create(name: 'community')
housing_category = Category.where(name: 'housing').first_or_create(name: 'housing')
jobs_category = Category.where(name: 'jobs').first_or_create(name: 'jobs')
personals_category = Category.where(name: 'personals').first_or_create(name: 'personals')
services_category = Category.where(name: 'services').first_or_create(name: 'services')
for_sale_category = Category.where(name: 'for_sale').first_or_create(name: 'for sale')
```

Subcategories are stored in the community category. The subcategories are also created in my seeds.rb file. Here are the subcategories in the community category:

```
Subcategory.where(name: 'activities', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'activities', category_id: community_category.id)
Subcategory.where(name: 'classes', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'classes', category_id: community_category.id)
Subcategory.where(name: 'events', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'events', category_id: community_category.id)
Subcategory.where(name: 'general', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'general', category_id: community_category.id)
Subcategory.where(name: 'new', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'news', category_id: community_category.id)
Subcategory.where(name: 'musicians', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'musicians', category_id: community_category.id)
Subcategory.where(name: 'pets', category_id: community_category.id).first_or_create(name: 'pets', category_id: community_category.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `@community` variable like this:

```rb
@categories = Category.all
@community = @categories[0]
```

So when there are no categories in your database `@community` is `nil`.

Which causes a problem in `app/views/categories/index.html.erb:29` where you call `category_path(@community)`. Since `@community` is `nil` it evaluates to `category_path(nil)`. Hense the error.

You should check if `@community` is present before showing this `link`.

Comment: The error message in line 1 of you snippet shows

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id])

It goes wrong here in the view in line 26:

<%= link_to 'community', category_path(@community) %></th>

Please post the controller code.

Comment: I have added my categories_controller.rb and my routes.rb files.

Comment: What do you store inside `@community`? Please show where it is created, seems like it is some incorrect object `category_path()` expects persisted `Category` instance as an argument

Comment: I have added snippets to my seeds.rb file which is where the community category was created. It also contains the subcategories stored inside the community category.

Comment: The issue is at line `29` (with `category_path(@community)`  call) in `app/views/categories/index.html.erb`. Probably this `@community` is set in Categories controller, can you show this file?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was inattentive, you did show it... my bad

Comment: Thank you, I put `<th class="table-header"><%= link_to 'community', category_path(@community) %></th>`into this statement:`<% if Category.exists?(1) %>`
This seems to have gotten rid of the "missing required keys: [:id]" error.